# Appended div couldn't scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, web

In google chrome I append a div. When I click the button the red div will slide out but it can't scroll with mouse wheel.

The bug **only happens in google chrome**.

This is an example page:http://infinitynewtab.com/question/test.html

html, css and js:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #right{
        width:350px;
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:-350px;
        background-color: red;
        overflow-y:scroll; 
    }
    #button{
        width:180px;
        height:40px;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color:rgb(75, 197, 142);
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        color:#fdfdfd;
        border-radius: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slideOut{
        0% {
            transform:translate(0px); 
            -webkit-transform:translate(0px); 
        }
        100% {
            transform:translate(-350px);
            -webkit-transform:translate(-350px);
        }
    }
    .slideOut{
        animation:slideOut ease 0.3s;
        -webkit-animation:slideOut ease 0.3s;
        transform:translate(-350px);
        -webkit-transform:translate(-350px);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="button">Click me,then scroll in the red area</div>
<script src="jquery2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var str='';
        for (var i = 0; i <10000; i++) {
            str+=i+'<br>';
        };
        $('body').append('<div id="right">'+str+'</div>');
    });
    $("#button").on('click',function(event) {
        /* Act on the event */
        $('#right').addClass('slideOut');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on mouse move scroll?

Comment: Works in Chrome 39.0.2171.95

Comment: My English is not very good,I means it just can't scroll by mouse wheel on the red div

Comment: Select/Highlight texts for scrolling ?

Answer (score 2):

You cat try it may be it's help

CSS add z index as like this

```
 #right{
z-index:2;
}
#button{
z-index:1;
}
```

Live [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/uggcoxu3/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `slideOut` class. Not sure why. But this works:

```
.slideOut{
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in;
        transition: all .3s ease-in;
        right: 0 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to scroll don't set the div's height to 100%.
The way you implemented this you can scroll only after focusing the div. this is not a bug...

Comment: I want the red div can scroll,I set the div height to 600px,but it still can't scroll.But it can scroll in ie:[link](http://infinitynewtab.com/question/test.html)

Comment: Set the height to auto

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good, what I want to say is, the page does not scroll, but the content in div can scroll.

Comment: Can be a bug... If you resize the window the div will scroll.
A workaround could be to get chrome to redraw it.
Maybe try to focus() it or change a css attribute

Comment: Thank you,I will try your suggesstion